# li-tags are vertically aligned in ul-tag but not the text itself

Tags: html, css

My pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/pCdBe

I have aligned 3 li elements in an ul-tag vertically with percent values considerung the height of the parent ul.

I also want that the li elements text like 1 or 2 is vertically aligned and there is still a bug in the pen.

Why is there  such a gap on the left side of the numbers?

```
 <ul id="navigationWheeler" >
    <li>1</li>
    <li style="background-color: #0094ff;">2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul> 

#navigationWheeler {
    height: 300px;
    width:30px;
    text-align: center;   
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: black solid 1px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

 li{
  list-style:none;
  height:33%;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`li` tags align themselves vertically but not their content, so in order to align the content vertically either you need to use `display: table-cell;` or `line-height` property

```
li{
    list-style:none;
    height:33%;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vnKyH/)

Also I don't think you are resetting the stylesheet in your codepen demo, search for CSS reset and you will get loads of reset stylesheets which will reset the browser applied default styles.

Comment: When I increase the height of the parent container then the vertical alignment of the children is not correct anymoe due to line-height 'hack'.

Comment: Thanks for the css reset hint which I have read after reading it up in google. Clicking your demo link does not mean I have read your answer I hope you understand... ;-)

Comment: @Elisa No grudges, don't worry, I just told you that you must have made an answer, after reading `display: table-cell;`

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xHncd

```
#navigationWheeler {
    height: 300px;
    width:30px;
    text-align: center;   
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: black solid 1px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

 li{
  list-style:none;
  height:33%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It's a bit hacky, but you can keep percentage as the height for your li-tags.

Answer (score 0):

It appears some padding is being applied to the `ul`.  This is most likely the default styling of the browser and a CSS reset would remove this.  Remove this padding and place a width on the `ul` to horizontally center the elements.

```
navigationWheeler {
    height: 300px;
    width:30px;
    text-align: center;   
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: black solid 1px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Adding padding to the `li` elements can vertically center the text within them.

```
 li{
  list-style:none;
  height:33%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 50%;
}
```

**Working Example** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Djzhy

Comment: Take care that different browsers have different default values for paddings and margins on lists. (Some have padding where others have margin, etc.) So if you go set one margin with CSS, you are obliged to change all of them, and the paddings, on both the `ul` and the `li` elements, in order to remain compatible with all browsers.

Comment: pen looks buggy in chrome28

Answer (score -2):

All solutions I have seen so far work partly.

This is the full working pen:

- No padding/margin on ul-tag
- li-tags increase with the height of their parent by %.

http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/IfymB

```
<ul id="navigationWheeler" >
    <li>
      <div>1</div>
    </li>
    <li style="background-color: #0094ff;">
      <div>2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>3</div>
    </li>
  </ul> 

#navigationWheeler {
    height: 300px;
    width:30px;
    text-align: center;   
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: black solid 1px;
    background-color: lightgray;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

 li{
  list-style:none;
  height:33%;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  display:table;
}

div{
  width:30px;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This is what I answered :) *you need to use display: table-cell;* OR *line-height*

Comment: you should really make your ul the table, your lis table-row and div table-cell

Comment: @Mr.Alien Have you seen my comment?

Comment: @Elisa did you read my answer? I provided you `line-height` solution there, but also specified that `if` you want you can also use `display: table-cell`

Comment: @Mr.Alien I think your answer should have been accepted but don't think it's going to be, she can't even be bothered to upvote the answers we provided even though they helped her.

Comment: @Pete I saw that you deleted your answer, I don't mind she accepts my answer or not, but taking ideas from the answer and posting an answer which says that this works and I made it, that's bad..

Comment: @Mr.Alien I did not "steal" your answer and repost it. While you were posting your answer I was changing my pen with table/tablecell and the div inside the li-element which is a total individual approach I found out. And about table/tablecell I have read in google in the meantime. THEN I have read your answer but felt its not needed because mine already worked, can you live with that? I have no problem marking your answer because you gave me the hint with the padding:0; which I also use but not on ul commonly just html and body.

Comment: @Pete Thanks for your table-row hint which I have implemented.